# Python, Sqlite - Is there any way to neuter a condition in WHERE clause of a query?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have some Entry boxes on a form and a button that will search a db's table by executing a query that is composed of a *WHERE* clause with several conditions corresponding to the input boxes.
The user may or may not fill all the input boxes, so I just want to have a predefined query with all columns on the where clause like:

```
column01=? AND column02=? AND ... AND columnN=?
```

and then have a tuple or list which simply I have constructed on a loop where inputed data is placed on the same order, columns of the WHERE clause were arranged and each input only checked whether it was *""* (not been input) and if so the respective place in the list would be assigned ***something*** that makes that specific condition transparent!. To clarify myself, see what means if user filled **no** input box (imagine that thing would be an ***asterisk***):

```
"SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE column01=* AND ... AND columnN=*"
```

that is desirable to work like this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM sometable"
```

which bears no constrain on any column. Is this credible?

Comment: Check the [like option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: @ Christos Papoulas Thank you so much for exact & concise response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Christos correctly pointed out above, pattern matching in SQL queries is the way to do this and lots of other much more complicated things.
I just need to use *LIKE* instead of equality sign and assign `'%'` to any condition I want to make transparent. more information [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)